# Streaming HTTPs using Ruby

Tags: ruby, https, streaming

I wanted to open a https connection and keep it unclosed.  I will be getting an xml document, which I will be saving in a file as it gets streamed.

I tried net/https, but I was able to use Net::HTTP::Get.new() method, which stops after getting one response.

My primary use is to save the xml that I am downloading into chunks of file.

Any comments/thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer...
The Net::HTTP:Get method works fine, You just need to keep reading from the same response again!